# How can I find out what application is using the command line?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I occasionally see the Windows command line window open and close quickly after. I recently formatted, and I'm seeing the issue again.

It's irrationally annoying me, and I was wondering if there's a way to find out what's causing it.

Comment: On my PC, I've noticed it also, particularly during Windows update The process is transitory,  so difficult to track down, but SysInternals Process Explorer  might show it running under one of the *svchost* instances (see the lower lower pane, Ctrl-L). As you say, it's a minor annoyance  but probably not of any significance.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I've been seeing it open much more often as of late, which is why I'm curious as to what's going on. I've installed the application you mention, should I just keep it open until the next time I notice the command line used?

Comment: @CConard96 Thanks, I've searched but couldn't find similar questions. On first look it appears that could indeed be the same issue. I'll mark this as solved as soon as I can confirm.

Comment: Yes, though even with it running, the CMD window may disappear before you the source shows. You might also check *Scheduled Tasks* to see if there's on that coincides with the popup CMD prompt.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yeah, I checked the task handler before formatting, but it seems clicking on the library doesn't show ALL the tasks, which would explain why I couldn't find it. I have to go into Microsoft - Office to see the task I think is causing it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik You should have seen he said it closes quickly, so unless you are going to tell him how to deal with that then your suggestion is no use. And even then let's say it didn't close quickly, you still didn't tell him which thing to look for in process explorer, so all he has is a program a bit like task manager with no advice from you on where specifically to look. Suppose he does see cmd.exe under svchost. What should he look for then?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik and if you do figure out how to see what program launched a process, by using process explorer then you could always add that as an answer here https://superuser.com/questions/851692/track-which-program-launches-a-certain-process